# Create a tar with maven generated jar with dependenceis and few other files

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm new to maven and its interesting subject to learn.
Succeed to create a jar with dependencies, using:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Now, i have to include few shell scripts and generated jar to a tar.
To achieve this, i ve tried the following way:
Added

```xml
 <descriptors>
    <descriptor>hadoop-job.xml</descriptor>
 </descriptors>
```

to the above script.

In hadoop-job.xml i'm including required files into tar.

The problem is tar is generated first and says no *.jar found in target.
Is there a way to schedule jar creation first and tar next, since both the configurations reside in assembly plugin.
OR
Is there a command to execute and generate a jar first and then a command to generate a tar ?

By the way i'm executing mvn clean assembly:assembly -Dbinary=true.
Help me to resolve. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of assembly building the jar-with-dependencies and after that a tar that includes this jar-with-dependencies (built by the maven-assembly-plugin just before). In the tar I also includes the shell script files in `.sh` from the folder `src/main/bin`.

First, the plugin configuration :

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorId>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorId>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>all</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/all.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/assembly/</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**The order of the executions is important** because if I want to include the jar-with-dependencies into my tar I need to have it built before.

I put all the assemblies in the same folder, that's why I have a global `configuration` tag additionally to the `configuration` tag of the `executions`

And then the content of my assembly file all.xml :

```xml
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>all</id>
    <formats>
        <format>tar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory> 
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/bin</directory>
            <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
            <fileMode>755</fileMode>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The `includeBaseDirectory` is here to avoid my tar containing the root folder with the name of the project with the version.

If you don't specify the `outputDirectory` tags, the folder structure into your archive will begin from the root of the project, for example it will include your jar with the path `target/your-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

---

---

**EDIT :** The plugin configuration that I did before could be simplified with just the following :

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorId>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/all.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/assembly/</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The reason is because in the `maven-assembly-plugin` the `descriptorId` is read before the `descriptors` so that's good for our case but if not, we would need two executions as done higher with care about the order.
The same attention have to be done for the order of the `descriptors`, they are performed in the reading order (it can seems logic but I think it might be useful to indicate it).